# Do I need to verify the result for Google Invisible reCaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, verification, invisible-recaptcha

I am following the instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible)
to implement the **invisible recaptcha**. Everything works great, but how do I know it is working? Is there a way to force a false to test it?

Also, The documentation is not clear on the above page, but some places have additional code to verify the users "response" (it's invisible so i'm not sure what the response is here) - so do I need to add additional back end logic to hit [this](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) endpoint with the invisible `reCaptcha` resulting token and my secret key?

What happens when the user clicks submit on the invisible recaptcha? What is done in the API to return the token? What is the token for? What does the siteverify api then do to determine its a person? Why isnt additional verification needed when the reCAPTCHA V2 (visible click one) is used?

Comment: Have you seen https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify ?

Comment: Yes - but the documentation on the invisible implementation page is not clear on whether it is necessary to verify and some examples people have made do not have any code to verify (https://jsfiddle.net/jayh99/dp1cLh28/) while others do (http://www.pinnacleinternet.com/installing-invisible-recaptcha/) so - is it necessary?

Comment: Of course it is. What stops someone from scripting your form without it?

Comment: Im not sure what happens when .execute() is called - for all I know, that is when google verifies that the user is human and that is when the "data-callback" is triggered - it could be assumed that if the "data-callback" is not triggered then it wasnt a human and there isnt any further action. So if on .execute() of the invisible recaptcha, the recaptcha api is being hit - why isnt it validated then?

Comment: But what happens when the user scripts your form outside of the browser? Google code is not even executed.

Comment: Can I get a more detailed answer if you understand how it works, please share as an answer so me and the other unlearned programmers can understand? What happens when the user clicks submit on the invisible recaptcha? What is done in the API to return the token? What is the token for? What does the siteverify api then do to determine its a person? Why isnt additional verification needed when the reCAPTCHA V2 (visible click one) is used?

Comment: You will still have to verify the captcha on the server side, be it an invisible one or the classical v2. That is because you cannot prevent users from manually triggering/invoking the submit handler of the form (ie spoofing a submission and bypassing captcha check). You cannot verify the captcha in JSfiddle itself, because you need access to a server to perform the actual verification. Ps: the only difference between classical v2 recaptcha and the new invisible one is that the former depends on an injected widget while the latter does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing it looks like you could just do the front end part. The data callback function is not called until google is sure you are a person, if google is not sure then it loads the "select which tiles have a thing in them" reCaptcha to be sure. Once the reCaptcha api is sure that it is a person, the data callback function is fired - at that time you can do further validation to ensure that the token you received during the callback is the one that google actually sent and not a bot trying to fool you by hitting your callback funct - so from there you do server side processing for further validation. Below is an example of a C# ashx handler - and ajax for the validation

```
function onTestSubmit(token) {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testHandler.ashx",
            data: { token: token },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == "True") {
                    //do stuff to submit form
                }
            }
        });            
    }
```

And the ashx

```
    public class testHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string token = context.Request.Form["token"];
        bool isCaptchaValid = ReCaptcha.Validate(token);

        context.Response.Write(isCaptchaValid.ToString());
    }


    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    }

    public class ReCaptcha
    {
        private static string URL = 
    "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}";
        private static string SECRET = "shhhhhhhhhhhhhhSecretTOken"; 

        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }

        public static bool Validate(string encodedResponse)
        {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedResponse)) return false;
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var googleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format(URL, SECRET, encodedResponse));
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var reCaptcha = serializer.Deserialize<ReCaptcha>(googleReply);
        return reCaptcha.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do. 
You need to understand that invisible reCaptcha is a process with multiple steps, all of which end up providing a final response regarding the humanity of the user.

In simple words, when the users submits a form (or does whatever it is you are trying to keep bots away from with Invisible reCaptcha) you'll be sending your public sitekey to your backend, which will fire up a verification payload to Google.

In my very basic example, this is the button which the hopefully human visitor clicks to submit a form on my site:

```
<button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxx_obscured_xxxxxxxx" data-callback="onSubmit">Submit Form</button>
```

Note how the the button has the data-callback "onSubmit", which upon submission runs this small script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var onSubmit = function(response) {
    document.getElementById("simpleForm").submit(); // send response to your backend service
  };
</script>
```

The backend service in my example is a vanilla PHP script intended to process the form input and store it on a database and here comes the tricky part. As part of the POST to the backend, besides the form fields the user filled is the response from the service (and since you may or may not be doing a lot of things on the front-end where the user could manipulate the response before it's posted to your backend, Google's response is not explicit at this point)

On your backend, you'll need to take g-recaptcha-response that came from google and post it to a verification API using your **private key** (which is not the one on the form) in order to get the human/robot verdict which you can act upon. Here's a simple example written in PHP and hitting the API with cURL:

```
$recaptcha_response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];    
    $api_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $api_secret = 'zzzzzzz_OBSCURED_SECRET_KEY_zzzzzzzzzzz';
    $remoteip = '';

    $data = array('secret' => $api_secret, 'response' => $recaptcha_response);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);

    $captcha_response = json_decode($result, true);

    // at this point I have the definite verdict from google. Should I keep processing the form?.
    if ($captcha_response['success'] == true) {
      // I heart you, human. Keep going
      $captcha_error = 0;
    }

    else {
      // Damn robot, die a slow and painful death
      $captcha_error = 1;
    }
```

I make a final decision based on $captcha_error (basically 1 means halt, 0 means keep processing)

If you rely solely on getting the g-recaptcha-response you're having Google do the work and then ignoring the result